# undefined method 'shift' for class nil:NilClass in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, methods

I'm trying to run a mincut algorithm (for a class), and this works on smaller test cases, but whenever I put a bigger test case (eventually leading up to the assignment problem), I get this error:

"(eval):1049: undefined method `shift' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

I suspect there may be a certain case where the program crashes, but I can't figure it out. If someone could help me that'd be great!

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 7], [2, 1, 3, 4], [3, 1, 2, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3, 5], [5, 4, 6, 7, 8], [6, 5, 7, 8], [7, 1, 5, 6, 8], [8, 5, 6, 7]]

mincut = 8
count = 10

def clean(a, i, j)                        #When collapsing two nodes together, scans
    z = a[j][0]                           #all elements and changes value of second
    m = a[i][0]                           #index to first, i.e. all 2's become 1's. 
    a.each_index do |x|
        a[x].each_index do |y|
            if a[x][y] == z
            a[x][y] = m
            end
        end
    end
end

def delete_loops!(a, i)                   #scans concatenated array, removes all duplicates of the first element
    z = a[i].shift
        a[i].reject!{ |item| item == z}
    a[i].unshift(z)
end

def collapse!(a, i, j)          #collapses two nodes together
    clean(a, i, j)
    a[i].concat(a[j])           #concatenates the second array into the first
    a.delete_at(j)              #deletes second array
    delete_loops!(a, i)
end

def random(a)                   #picks random nodes to collapse, and returns their 
    t = rand(a.size)            #positions in the array.
    s = a[t][1 + rand(a[t].size - 1)]
    for x in 0..a.size-1
        if a[x][0] == s
        s = x
        break
        end
    end
return t, s
end

for x in 0..count do            #repeats the program x amount of times, returns
    while a.size > 2 do         #the lowest value of the minimum cut.
        i, j = random(a)
        collapse!(a, i, j)
    end
    size = a[0].size - 1

    if size < mincut
        mincut = size
    end
end
puts mincut
```

To sum up the program, it computes the minimum cut in a graph, by doing a set amount of runs and retaining the minimum cut returned. the area which seems to be troublesome is my "delete_loops!" function, which, essentially, checks an array to see if any of the elements matches the first element of the array, and then deletes duplicates of said first element. I used the "shift" and "unshift" methods to do this (by removing then re-inserting the first element, I was having trouble not deleting the first element in the process).

I think it's either a certain case that may be causing it to crash, or the way I'm executing it is giving me trouble. any ideas?

```
    #edit: full error message, from the codecademy scratchpad

(eval):1122: undefined method `shift' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):1131:in `collapse!'
    from (eval):1149
    from (eval):1146:in `each'
    from (eval):1146

#and from my command line try (reading a text file with same array):

test.rb:29:in 'delete_loops!" : undefined method 'shift' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>
    from test.rb:38:in 'collapse!'
    from test:rb:56:in 'block in <main>'
    from test.rb:53:in 'each'
    from test.rb:53:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Post full stack trace.

Comment: Clearly, 'a' is nil, so I'd put in some asserts to verify that the parameters make sense (a is not nil, and i is in range). You can back up to find the problem if an assert fails.

Comment: When debugging such problems, I recommend using a debugger. It helps *a lot* to step through the code and inspect live values.

Comment: where can I find a debugger? I went to Ideone.com and it just gave me the same output

Comment: As a note, `for x in 0..count do` should be `(count+1).times do |x|`. It's extremely unusual to see the `for` construct employed in Ruby. Remember `0..count` is `[0, 1, 2, ... count]`, or `0..2` is `[0, 1, 2]` so you might have an off-by-one error here.

Comment: For the debugger have a look at the [debugger gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) or the [pry-debugger gem](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the random value assigned to the variable i is the last possible array element.

So when collapse! does the a.delete_at(j) the variable i is then pointing to the index of the last element + 1 (whichi is to say no element, since it's now outside the range of the shortened array)

I think you want i to be pointing to the same element regardless of the fact that its position in the array has changed because element j is deleted, so...

add the following decrement between the delete_at and the call to delete_loops!...to handle the case of the array pointed to by i is no longer in the same position...

```
a.delete_at(j)
i -= 1 if i >= j
delete_loops!(a, i)
```

Come to think of it, if the random number assigned to i and j are equal you'll also have a problem...

so you may want to change the call to collapse!...

```
collapse!(a, i, j) if i != j
```